# Before Catalina, do live photos count as both photo and video in the "Photos" app tally?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, photos

I'm just wondering whether live photos were counted twice because they were photos but also videos. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious...iCloud is based on storage space, not a tally of file types.  Why and where would this matter?

Answer (score 1):

No, they weren't counted twice in Mojave for example.